# React + Flux: How to reset the store?

Tags: javascript, authentication, reactjs, flux

When the user `logs out` I need to reset the store of that `session`. Because when a `different user logged in again the previous users store is reflecting`.

Comment: Just create a flux action that is called when the user logs out that will reset your store to the default

Comment: Thank you Mike. But is there a default method in the flux to reset the store?

Comment: I don't believe vanilla flux has a reset method

Comment: Thank you Mike....

Answer (score 0):

You can try [redux-reset-store](https://github.com/abhiaiyer91/redux-reset).

Answer (score -1):

Reload the page (`location.reload()`) when the user logs out.